# SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION structure

Tags: data-structures, sysinternals

From where does this structure originates? I know that it is declared in famous ntdll.h and is a part of undocumented windows API. But isn't it vary between different versions of windows? Is there a way to dump this structure from working system? I tried 'dt SYSTEM_HANLDE_INFORMATION' in Windbg and 'type SYSTEM_HANLDE_INFORMATION' in SoftIce but all I get is 'no such symbol' message. I also dumped ntoskrnl.pdb with PdbDump.exe and searched among the dumped structures - and could not find neither SYSTEM_HANLDE_INFORMATION nor SYSTEM_HANLDE.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 6):

You can refer to [this paper on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/OpenedFileFinder.aspx) on querying all open handles to files, where it is defined as:

```
typedef struct _SYSTEM_HANDLE
{
    DWORD    dwProcessId;
    BYTE     bObjectType;
    BYTE     bFlags;
    WORD     wValue;
    PVOID    pAddress;
    DWORD    GrantedAccess;
}
SYSTEM_HANDLE;
```