# c++ file synchronization issues

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

i have c++ program (turbo c++ ver 3) that write/read data into files.
when multiple instances of the program is run and at particular point of execution , when the two instance of the program open and write into the file at the same time , some information is lost

```
if(!filein)
```

is not ideal for this situation. Its a issue with sync i guess

Is there any way that i can check if the file is opened or not before performing any operation

thank you

Comment: Please post more code. Like the code used to open the files.

Comment: You need file locks, which are not implemented in the standard library. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/839856/1175253

Comment: You need a mutex to coordinate access to the file.  Can you use operating system APIs?  If so, what platform are you targeting?

Comment: @CareyGregory Its not a complex program. im an absolute beginner and i have no idea what u r talking about

Comment: @Sam im using turbo c++. i cant find any  LockFileEx() but there is lock(); can i use it

Comment: Please add more info about the compiler and target API/headers. In newer versions, you should have CreateFile() and even  LockFile() (win32). But then, you can't/shouldn't use fstreams. Sometimes, you need to 'elevate' the Windows API version by setting the macro 'WINVER' to an appropriate value, e.g. 0x0501 for Windows XP.

Comment: If boost is not an option, you can indeed use lock(), open(), sopen(), read(), write() and close(), they seem to be defined in "IO.H".

Comment: @Sam - It doesn't matter if it's a simple program.  You need some way of controlling access to the file.  What operating system are you using?  Windows?

Comment: @Carey Gregory - You're right, but there are several methods to do this, so yes, we need to know the target platform (most likely Windows, since turbo C++ is for Windows). I claim, that file locks are mandatory in such implementations, whether access synchronization is done using a global mutex for all processes, or another waiting mechanism on the file itself like this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7621248/1175253 (I'd prefer this approach).

Comment: @Sam - Sure, you should use file locking, but using that to synchronize access means you have to use spin locks, which are really inefficient.  I would use a mutex to synchronize access and locking to prevent processes other than my own from accessing the file.  (And, honestly, I didn't even know Turbo C++ still existed.)

Comment: The OP may consider replacing his toolchain with MSVC, or MinGW + Code::Blocks or Eclipse. I'd also choose mutexes, however, that wouldn't prevent another program from trying to access that file. In my previous comment, I failed to explain my thoughts thoroughly: Instead of spinning after a failed open(), I'd just wait on that global mutex, if the file is locked by another instance of the same program.

Answer (score 1):

If you have boost available then the easiest/best way is to embed the mutex into the file itself using `boost::interprocess::file_lock` ([docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html#interprocess.synchronization_mechanisms.file_lock))